# Calculating Wavelength Required To Break Bonds Using The Photon Energy Equation: ${λ = \frac{hc}{E}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, chemistry

I'm asking this here because it's a maths type question
I seem to get a much warmer response here despite making silly mistakes:

My friend told me he is going to use `365nm` light to irradiate `Ibotenic acid` -> `Muscazone`
I mentioned to him that this is barely below the visible spectrum and that you need a specific amount of energy to break bonds using photons, so I went on a little adventure:

First I had to calculate the bond energy of each species which was very tedious, I wonder if there is a better way:

```
Ibotenic acid:
O-H  = 2*463
C--N = 615
C-C  = 3*346
C--C = 602
C-O  = 3*358
N-O  = 201
C-N  = 2*305
C--O = 799
N-H  = 2*391  
{Total bond energy = 6037 kj/mol}

Muscazone:
O-H  = 463
C-O  = 3*358
C-C  = 3*346
C--C = 602
N-O  = 201
C-N  = 4*305
C--O = 799
N-H  = 3*391

Total Bond energy = 6570 kj/mol
```

$$
 E=6037000-6570000=-533000j\cdot mol^{-1}
$$

planck equation:

$$
\lambda = \frac{hc}{E}
$$

Dimensional analysis:
$$
\lambda = \frac{j\cdot s\cdot m}{j\cdot s\cdot n} \Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{m}{n}
$$

---

Seems that I can't get rid of `n` or `mol` so I used avogadros number:

$$
\lambda = \frac{(6.63\cdot 10^{-34})  (2.99\cdot 10^{8})}{(-533000)
(6.02\cdot 10^{23})}
$$

$$
\lambda = 224nm
$$

---

Is my reasoning, maths and answer correct?

Comment: The calculation of $\lambda$ is wrong. Check the calculation of $\frac{(6.63\times10^{-34})(2.99\times10^8)}{(-533000)(6.02\times10^{23})}$

Comment: hmmm? help me out @jjagmath

Comment: $\frac{(6.63\times10^{-34})(2.99\times10^8)}{(-533000)(6.02\times10^{23})} =  -6.17819\times 10^{-55}$ 
I have no idea how you got 224.

Comment: I just done the calculation again and I got -0.0000002238 so 224nm, but I done it on my phone so perhaps it's came out wrong @jjagmath

Comment: You are calculating $\frac{(6.63\times10^{-34})(2.99\times10^8)(6.02\times10^{23})}{(-533000)}$

Comment: @jjagmath tell me if I’m calculating it wrong please: https://www.dropbox.com/s/01nzl4f3qxnuzgf/Video%2010-03-2021%2C%2017%2054%2004.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Is my answer valid @jjagmath?

Comment: You are using wrong the calculator. You wrote $a*b÷c*d$, so you got $\frac{a b}{c} d = \frac{a b d}{c}$. If you want $\frac{a b}{c d}$ you need to write in the calculator $a*b÷(c*d)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120717/discussion-between-nickotine-and-jjagmath).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are just a couple of notes that might help you understand the problem better:

- There is no better way to calculate the total bond energy $E_{mole}$
- Since the final energy is larger, it means that the molecules must absorb energy to transform into the final product. That's the meaning of the $-$ sign.
- One photon is absorbed by one molecule, so you need to calculate the bond energy per molecule $E_{molecule}=E_{mole}/N_A$
- Transform this energy to wavelength $$\lambda=\frac{hc}{E_{molecule}}=\frac{hcN_A}{E_{mole}}$$

Comment: I thought the negative sign meant the reaction gives out energy? Before I do something stupid what is ${N_A}$? avogadros number? Also did I actually calculate anything at all or was it just completely wrong? @Andrei

Comment: @LordCommander can you help me out?

Comment: @Nickotine you are right. Higher bond energy means more stable. So you probably just need to calculate the wavelength to break only certain bonds. But the chemistry of that is out of my expertise. And yes, $N_A$ is Avogadro's number

Comment: I think I accidently got this right, can you show me the full derivation?

Comment: Because the way I entered it in the calculator is just how your equation is

Comment: the way I used my calculator it ended putting avogadros number at the top, but can I ask how you knew it was supposed to me at the top? @Andrei

Comment: Look at my last equation. In the middle term I've just used the point above, that a photon interacts with only one molecule, so the energy is the energy of a mole of molecules divided by Avogadro's number. $$\frac1{\frac{E_{mole}}{N_A}}=\frac{N_A}{E_{mole}}$$

Comment: I find that hard to understand, I’m bad at maths, can you show me with dimensional analysis using the planck equation? @andrei

Comment: $[h]=Js$, $[c]=m/s$, $[E_{mole}]=J/mole$, $[N_A]=1/mole$. To get Joules, you need to take $J/mole$ and multiply with $mole$, or equivalently divide by $1/mole$, so $$[\lambda]=m=\frac{Js\cdot m/s}{(J/mole)/(1/mole)}=\frac{Js\cdot m/s\cdot 1/mole}{J/mole}$$

Comment: @Nickotine could you properly parametrize your equation for $\lambda$ in your post, so we don't have to look at numbers and guess :)

Comment: As you can see there is no way to get rid of `n` so my understanding of `1/mol` being at the bottom is wrong, so how does it actually work?: $${\lambda = \frac{j\cdot s\cdot m}{j\cdot s\cdot (1/n)}}\Rightarrow{\lambda=\frac{j\cdot s\cdot m}{\dfrac{j\cdot s}{n}}}\Rightarrow{\lambda=\frac{m}{n}}$$ @LordCommander

Comment: ${\lambda = \frac{j\cdot s\cdot m}{j\cdot s\cdot (1/n)}}=\frac{j\cdot s}{j \cdot s}\cdot\frac{m}{\frac{1}{n}}=n\cdot m$

Comment: Oh yeah you’re right but I still can’t get rid of n that way @LordCommander

Comment: No you can't. If your age depends on how many $years$ you were alive, then it depends on it. That's it :)

Comment: Now what @LordCommander?

Comment: What can i help you with?